# Outliers odd behaviour

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, outliers

I got a sample of data. I applied a linear correction to it and then I calculate again the mean and standard deviation. The mean and the standard deviation before and after the correction are almost identical. When I plot their box plots the data after correction have bigger outliers than before. What I don't understand is: if the mean and standard deviation are almost identical how is it possible the two two samples to have such a big difference in outliers?

Comment: I suggest that you compute the skewness and the kurtosis. This will give you some idea of what is going on. I would bet that the kurtosis has increased, meaning that some values became closer to the mean and others further away from the mean, thus leaving the standard deviation similar. However, this is not characteristic of a linear transformation...

Comment: @Gina Can you please an example of what you're talking about? It's difficult to tell what the issue might be from your description